# XML Replace node

Tags: php, xml

I need my php SimpleXML script to rearrange a specific XML node with its value.

```
 $xml = file_get_contents('oldfile.xml');
 $xmlo = new SimpleXMLElement( $xml );

 $xmlo->asXML("new.xml");
```

I need to get the node Category and replace it from his parent node to another node. Example:

**This is how is currently have it:**

```
<bpxml>
<article>
<title></title>
<Group soort="CE" versie="1.0">
<category>test</category>
</Group>
</article>
</bpxml>
```

**This is how i needs to become:**

```
<bpxml>
<article>
<title></title>
<category>test</category>
</article>
</bpxml>
```

Answer (score 0):

This variant maybe silly and stupid, but it should do the work

```
$lines = explode("\n", $xml);
$newlist = array();

foreach($lines as $items) {
    $line = trim($items);

    if($line != "<Group soort=\"CE\" versie=\"1.0\">" || $line != "</Group>") {
        $newlist[] = $line;
    }
}

echo implode("\n", $newlist);
```